# What type of Array to store int value even if app gets closed/shutdown iOS

Tags: c++, ios, nsuserdefaults, nsnumber, screen-capture

I am trying to count how many screen captures a user made in my app. Unfortunately I am new to Objective C and really never worked with different type of Arrays or how to store things in them.

After a screen capture is made I want to call the method screenshotTaken in **MLBookMarkDataProvider.m** from my **main.m** class (where the screenshot got taken). I wanna store the int code in an Array that does not get cleared out after not using the method/class or app gets closed.

How shall I accomplish this ? I assume this is not rocket science for someone more experienced within C, all code examples is greatly appreciated. Regards!

**main.h**

```
 int code;
 ……
```

**main.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
 {
 ………..
  self.bookmarkDataProvider = [[MLBookmarkDataProvider alloc] initWithDelegate:self];
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(screenshotTaken) name:UIApplicationUserDidTakeScreenshotNotification object:nil];

 }

- (void) screenshotTaken
 {
 code ++;

 [self.bookmarkDataProvider screenshotTaken:code];
 }
```

**MLBookmarkDataProvider.m**

```
- (void) screenshotTaken : (int) code
{
  // Some code here, the Array(NSUserDefaults) below gets cleared after closing main.m class or shutting down the app :( 

  NSNumber *number = [NSNumber numberWithInt:code];
 [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:number forKey:@"ArrayNumber"];

if(Array has more then 5 items… blabla..){

    NSLog(@"Print Array:%@",number);
    // NSLog(@"code:%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really know why you would use an array to accomplish such thing, i would just save an integer in NSUserDefualts like this.

```
-(void)increaseScreenshotCount{
    //this will work even the first time when your key does not exist
    //get the value from UserDefaults and increase it ++
    NSInteger CurCount = 0 ;
    CurCount += [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"ScreenShotCount"];
    CurCount++;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:CurCount forKey:@"ScreenShotCount"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    NSLog(@"Current Screenshot Count %d", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] integerForKey:@"ScreenShotCount"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Better way to store value in app even you app get closed/shutdown. Please Use .plist file to store value and retrive value from .plist file. It will improve your app performance also without failing.